# PHP download removes digital code signature

Tags: php, windows, download, exe, code-signing

I have a `php` web application that allows our users to download our software installer `setup.exe`.

We've just started signing our code, both the the installer and the applications within it, which is all fine. However when I upload this installer to our web server, and download it through the `php` web application, `setup.exe` is no longer digitally signed!  It's as if it was never signed in the first place.

Here's what I've tried:

1. `[right click] -> [properties]` shows that `setup.exe` is not code signed. However `setup.exe` is the expected version.
2. I ran the installer, and installed our software. The applications that are installed ARE code signed, and the expected version matching the installer.
3. I tried downloading `setup.exe` directly from the web server through the `cpanel` File Manager and this is fine - `setup.exe` is digitally signed and the expected version.
4. Attempts to download `setup.exe` from the web site via different browsers (firefox, edge) result in the same behaviour.

EDIT

5. I also tried moving the `setup.exe` file to a public area on the site, and downloading it *directly* through the browser - **works perfectly.** All I can think is that the issue has to be in how PHP is serving the application to the browser.

I thought the HTTP headers or the PHP download function we have written might be related to the problem.

Our generic `include.php` file has the following headers to prevent caching:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 2016 01:00:00 GMT");   // a date in the past
```

And this is our download function:

```
function DownloadFile($file, $filename) {
    // check if file exists and write header info and output file
    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/x-msdownload');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        return true;
    } 
    else { 
        // file does not exist
        return false; 
    }
}
```

Which is primarily from the `readfile()` [example on php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php). Are there any red flags here? What's going on?

Comment: How do you upload your installer ?

Comment: @IsmailRBOUH in this case it was uploaded through our CPanel web interface using File Manager, however as I mentioned I downloaded it through my browser and checked it - which was fine. Presumably the file itself, on the server, is OK.

Comment: No HTTP header is going to modify a binary file, certainly not in such a specific way. Try thinking of more likely reasons for this, such as a cached file on the server or client side.

Comment: Thanks @miken32.  But can the file be cached given the headers that it has been delivered with? Using the version numbers I have already confirmed that this is the file I am expecting.

Comment: @miken32 I moved the file to a public location on the site and attempted to download directly through the browser, which worked fine! I can only think that the way PHP is serving the file is causing this issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the way the web application serves the file following a header redirect to the same page - the page itself also serving other data as content.

After the call to `DownloadFile()` the rest of the page, including HTML content etc, was sent as part of the file - resulting in the additional data corrupting the digital signature.

The solution was to force the script to exit after the file was sent.

```
$file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/../product/release/' . $path;
DownloadFile($file, "ProductInstaller.exe");
exit; // prevent the rest of the page from being sent as part of the file
```